# use sleepy mongoose api to access mongodb installed on aws ec2 instance from iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, mongodb, ios4

I am working on an iphone app that is supposed to use mongodb mounted on an aws ec2 instance as it's backend. I have set up mongodb on the instance and also sleepy mongoose as the api and can perform the add, query etc. operations via ssh. But I want to use sleepy mongoose api to do the same from the iphone app code(xcode4). Can anybody help me with this?

(P.S.-I have implemented the same using the mongodb's own rest api but am confused about how to use sleepy mongoose!)

Thanks
Piyali

Comment: This question was also asked on the [mongodb-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/DHCNlLGGa-k).  My suggestion there was to use consider using [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically 8 files and maybe 1000 lines of code, so between the source code and the [original blog post](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/), you should have all you need. It's basically just using `curl` calls, so however you do web requests via x-code is how you use sleepy mongoose.

That stated, please don't use sleepy mongoose for anything serious or with sensitive data. It's just a project some 10gen engineer put together. It has a couple of unit tests, no security model and no guarantee of full coverage of the driver functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know how to do web requests via xcode but sleepy mongoose is installed on an amazon ec2 instance. So if I use the url 'http://localhost:27080' to make web requests like for querying a db on the ec2 instance my query should be 'http://localhost:27080/mydb/collection/_find', which if I use in my xcode program gives me 'Connection failed! Error - Could not connect to the server. http://localhost:27080/mydb/collection/_find'. I can use curl to get the output of these requests via ssh only after I remote login to my aws ec2 instance where I installed sleepy mongoose. Help!

Comment: With EC2 you should have an external IP for the machine. You will need to access the DB at that IP.

Comment: I do have an ip but replacing localhost with the elastic ip of ec2 instance in the url doesn't work too..

Comment: Have you opened the correct port? By default port `27080` will be blocked on EC2. You may need to reconfigure your sleepy mongoose to run on port `80` instead.

Comment: Well, it works from the app only if i start the sleepy mongoose on the web server through the terminal...(i.e. remotely connecting to my ec2 instance and running the sleepy mongoose using the command 'python httpd.py' there). So if i run that and then build and run my app, the url works but not otherwise! How to make it work without having to run sleepy mongoose through the terminal?

Comment: take a look at `screen` for making this happen... again though, sleepy mongoose is not really a production-level product so there may be other issues keeping the system running